# Queue#addAsync with Transaction loses task sometimes

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This is question about Google App Engine/Java.

I'm trying to add Task to Queue with async API with Transaction.

This is minimum sample to see the problem below.

https://gist.github.com/hogedigo/4e1943be5a3d3550a6ce

I loop 10 times and save an entity to datastore and add a task to queue, but some tasks seem to be lost sometimes.

I make transaction and pass the tx to Queue#addTask.
All entities are always saved, but some tasks are lost sometimes.
I'm afraid that there is no consistency even if I make transaction.

I don't call addAsync result future's get method.
I'm sure it will be OK if I get the future's result, but I don't want to do that because I need to run transactions concurrently.

The document below said "calling Transaction.commit() blocks on the result of all async calls made since the transaction started before committing it."

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async#Working_with_Async_Transactions

Transaction.commit blocks only datastore async calls?
And doesn't block taskqueue async calls?

Answer (score 0):

`addAsync()` returns a `Future<TaskHandle>`. In your position, I'd try adding future that to `futures`. That should at least reveal if there's a hidden `ExecutionException`.

Comment: I just tried to add futrues#add and I saw an ExecutionException as you said.

The cause of ExecutionException is IllegalArgumentException. I cannot see the exception message on the production log, so I ran on devappserver.

It said:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transaction has expired or is invalid
```

I wonder if I should not call future#get after commitAsync...

Comment: Is there a reason to commit asynchronously? If you do it synchronously, you'll know whether failures of the collected futures matter or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to run all transactions and API calls in it in parallel. The datastore async calls seem to be OK. Only Task Queue seem to have this problem...